# The geometric construction of the $90^\circ, 87^\circ, 3^\circ$ triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, geometric-construction

The construction of the $90^\circ, 45^\circ, 45^\circ$ and the $90^\circ, 60^\circ, 30^\circ$ triangles is well known.

How can be constructed a triangle with angles $90^\circ, 87^\circ, 3^\circ$ without using regular polygons? By "construction" I mean the determination of the proportion of its sides and the required internal angles by the common operations in plane geometry, like in the other triangles.

Is it possible to use the exterior angle theorem and the triangles $90^\circ, 72^\circ, 18^\circ$ and $90^\circ, 75^\circ, 15^\circ$ to construct geometrically the angle $18^\circ - 15^\circ= 3^\circ$? How this construction can be done?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "without using regular polygons"? Often any geometric construction of a $72^\circ$ or $36^\circ$ angle will be marketed as a "construction of a regular pentagon" because that's the most famous use for such an angle -- but very often it is possible to cut the construction short once that angle has been produced, without drawing the entire regular pentagon.

Comment: But sure -- once you have made an $18^\circ$ angle and a $15^\circ$ angle you can certainly subtract these. Just move one of the angles such that it shares the vertex and one of the legs with the other one (Euclid's proposition I:XXIII) -- or construct them with a shared vertex and leg from the beginning.

Comment: If you can construct a line segment of length $\sqrt 5$ and another of length $1$ then you're on your way.

Answer (score 7):

A hint: $3^\circ=45^\circ+30^\circ-72^\circ$. For $72^\circ$ however you have to know how to construct a regular pentagon or some golden ratio triangle.

Comment: $72^\circ$ can be computed by drawing a $72^\circ-72^\circ-36^\circ$ triangle and its angle bisector, then using the similarity.

Comment: @E.Girgin: How do you draw such a triangle?

Comment: "Drawing" here is a symbolical word for a diagram to work on. My suggestion was to compute $\cos72^\circ$ with using pure geometry, as OP requested.

Answer (score 4):

Following E.Girgin suggestion plus [Richmond's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon#Richmond.27s_method):

[image]

**Steps:**

1. Construct a regular hexagon $ABCDEF$ with centre $O$;
2. Construct a square in such a way that $\widehat{AOG}=75^\circ$;
   let $B'=BC\cap OG$ and take $A'\in FA$ such that $OA'\perp OB'$;
3. Let $\Gamma$ be the circle with centre $O$ through $A'$ and $M$ be the midpoint of $OA'$;
    let $N$ be the intersection between $OB'$ and the angle bisector of $\widehat{OMB'}$;
4. Let $A''$ be the point of intersection between $\Gamma$ and the parallel to $OA'$ through $N$;
5. $\color{red}{\widehat{AOA''}=3^\circ}$.

An equivalent construction through $3=\frac{72-60}{2\cdot 2}$:

[image]

**Steps:**

1. Let $AO=OB$ and $OA\perp OB$; let $\Gamma$ be the circle centered at $O$ through $A$;
2. Let $U,V,M$ be the midpoints of $BM,BO,OA$; let $W$ be the intersection between $UV$
    and the circumcircle of $BOM$, whose centre is clearly $U$;
3. Let $N=WM\cap OB$ and take $P\in\Gamma$ such that $NP\parallel OA$;
4. Take $Q\in\Gamma$ such that $QP=PO$;
5. By bisecting twice $\widehat{QOB}$, we get an angle with amplitude $\color{red}{3^\circ}.$